# Django double curly braces tag not loading in html templates

Tags: python, django, web, checkout

I am new here so I may have worded the title wrong I apologize if I did so.
So I created a checkout page in my django project for the user to purchase coins but it wont render the variable attribute on the browser it just shows up empty.

Here's the coinpack model.py code.

`

```
class Coinpack (models.Model):
  amount= models.CharField(max_length=50)    
  price= models.FloatField()
  image_url= models.CharField(max_length=3000)
```

`

Here's the coinpack views.py code.

`

```
def buycoins (request):
   buycoins = Coinpack.objects.all
   return render(request, 'buycoins.html', {'buycoins': buycoins})
```

`
Here's the html template code

`

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="row">
        {% for Coinpack in buycoins %}
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">{{ Coinpack.amount }}  coins</h5>
                  <p class="card-text"> ${{ Coinpack.price}}</p>
                  <a href="{% url 'checkout' Coinpack.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">Buy Now</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %} 
    </div>
    

{% endblock %}
```

`

After this the coipack page works well
[image]
but when I add the checkout page the attributes are not rendered, here's what I did.

checkout page views.py

`

```
def checkout(request, pk):
    checkout = Coinpack.objects.get(id=pk)
    context = {'checkout':checkout}
    return render(request, 'checkout.html', context)
```

`
checkout page url.py

`

```
 path('checkout/<int:pk>/', views.checkout, name="checkout"),
```

`

checkout page html template
`

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg">
                <br>
                <img src="{{Coinpack.image_url}}">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg">
                <br>
                <div class="card card-body">
                    <h3> {{coinpack.amount}} </h3>
                    <hr>
                    <h4>Total: $ {{Coinpack.price}} </h4>
                    <hr>
                    
                    </div
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>

</body>
```

`
This is the result in the browser
[image]

So I have no idea why it ends up empty pls help, thank you.

Comment: I see that the variable you're putting into the template is called checkout: `context = {'checkout':checkout}` But in the template, you reference fields called `Coinpack` and `coinpack`. I think you to change those variable names to match the variable you're passing to the template.

Answer (score 1):

You used the different variables in the template. Try this,

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg">
                <br>
                <img src="{{checkout.image_url}}">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg">
                <br>
                <div class="card card-body">
                    <h3> {{checkout.amount}} </h3>
                    <hr>
                    <h4>Total: $ {{checkout.price}} </h4>
                    <hr>                   
               </div
            </div>
        </div>       
    </div>
</body>
```